# How to display parent table data in asp.net Entity Framework scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My parent class is

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }       
    public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Food> Foods { get; set; }
}
```

My child class

```
public class Food
{
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public string FoodType { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

I want to save a food item with a restaurant.

This is my create controller

```
var restaurants = db.Restaurants.ToList();

ViewBag.restaurant =
            restaurants.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.RestaurantId.ToString(), Text = x.RestaurantName });

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Foods.Add(food);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But in the display list it only shows the `restaurantID`.

[image]

I want to show corresponding `restaurentName` for each `RestaurantId` from the `Restaurant` table.

How can I do this ?

Comment: are you sure this column is bound to the right property? where do you read it out, and do you go with lazy or eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your field name in the view from **restaurantID** to **Restaurant.RestaurantName**